# set current time with timezone

Tags: android

my current time is ct: 
ct string is About 4 hours less than my hour

Comment: Welcome to SO. *Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [su].*

Answer (score 1):

For getting the  time based on Time  Zone , use the below  code

```
 Date today = new Date();

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
        String IST = df.format(today);
```

Comment: Thank .now i would Run a code at a specified time

Answer (score 0):

```
i use it and work foe me:
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
String time = String.format("%02d" , c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))+":"+
            String.format("%02d" , c.get(Calendar.MINUTE))+":"+
.                   String.format("%02d" , c.get(Calendar.SECOND))+":"+
    .           String.format("%03d" , c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
```

Comment: but how to get my current date

Comment: in format yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Thank .now i would Run a code at a specified time

Answer (score 0):

Below code will log device time and time zone. If you need time specific to zone other than device, please use @shiva Snape answer

```
    long milliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis(); //Long.parseLong(name);
    java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdff = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
    Date resultdate = new Date(milliseconds);
    String ct=sdff.format(resultdate);
    Log.i("Time", ct);
```

Comment: Thank .now i would 
Run a code at a specified time